# MySQL query (CustomerID and dates of 1st, 2nd and 3rd purchases)

Tags: mysql, northwind

I am trying to create a dashboard with customer ID and dates of 1st, 2nd and 3rd purchases. I use MySQL, Northwind db.

My query works perfectly fine for the 1st purchase, but I do not understand how to find 2nd and 3rd purchase date for each customer.

Now I'm trying to do next: 2nd_purchase_date is the next MIN(OrderDate) after 1st_purchase_date but I get following error 'Invalid use of group function'

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;
CREATE TABLE t1
(
    CustomerID varchar(5),
    OrderDate datetime,
    OrderID int,
    i int
);

INSERT INTO t1(CustomerID, OrderDate, OrderID, i)
SELECT CustomerID, min(OrderDate), min(OrderID),1
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CustomerID;

INSERT INTO t1(CustomerID, OrderDate, OrderID, i)
SELECT CustomerID,min(OrderDate), min(OrderID),2
FROM Orders
WHERE min(OrderDate) 
NOT IN 
(
SELECT CustomerID, min(OrderDate), min(OrderID)
FROM Orders
)
GROUP BY CustomerID;

INSERT INTO t1(CustomerID, OrderDate, OrderID, i)
SELECT CustomerID,min(OrderDate), OrderID,3
FROM Orders
WHERE min(OrderDate) 
NOT IN 
(
SELECT CustomerID, min(OrderDate), min(OrderID) FROM Orders
)
GROUP BY CustomerID;
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and a desired result

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the last example [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx), you can use the `LIMIT offset, count` feature in combination with `ORDER BY column ASC` to select the entry with the second purchase date for a single user (with the id *XXX* replaced with the respective value):

```
SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate, OrderID
  FROM Orders
  WHERE CustomerID = XXX
  ORDER BY OrderDate ASC
  LIMIT 1, 1;
```

or the entry with the third purchase date:

```
SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate, OrderID
  FROM Orders
  WHERE CustomerID = XXX
  ORDER BY OrderDate ASC
  LIMIT 2, 1;
```

... and so on.

---

You get the first entry via

```
SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate, OrderID
  FROM Orders
  WHERE CustomerID = XXX
  ORDER BY OrderDate ASC
  LIMIT 0, 1;
```

or the equivalent:

```
SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate, OrderID
  FROM Orders
  WHERE CustomerID = XXX
  ORDER BY OrderDate ASC
  LIMIT 1;
```

---

This should give you the first three orders for a single customer:

```
SELECT CustomerID, OrderDate, OrderID
  FROM Orders
  WHERE CustomerID = XXX
  ORDER BY OrderDate ASC
  LIMIT 3;
```

While the following is definitely not good from a performance perspective, it should still work to give you the first three orders for each customer:

```
SELECT o1.CustomerID, o1.OrderDate, o1.OrderID
  FROM Orders o1
  WHERE o1.OrderID IN
        (SELECT o2.OrderID
           FROM Orders o2
           WHERE o1.CustomerID = o2.CustomerID
           ORDER BY o2.OrderDate ASC LIMIT 3)
  ORDER BY o1.CustomerID, o2.OrderDate ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you, Carsten. I would like to clarify my question. I'm trying to find 1st, 2nd and 3rd purchases for each customer, not just first 3. MySQL LIMIT returns only 1 row. Did I missed something?

Comment: I added two more queries to the bottom of my answer, that should give you a hint about the direction you might wanna go.

Comment: @IrinaBushmakina I left the WHERE clause out of my original answer in order to make the concept easier to understand. Sorry, that it was misleading. They are now included.